# Node.js soap request remove namespace from argument

Tags: node.js, soap, node-soap

I am unable to send the correct argument to the service.

Code used:

```
var soap = require('soap');
var url = 'http://example.com';

soap.WSDL.prototype.ignoredNamespaces = ['targetNamespace', 'typedNamespace'];

var args = {'name':'test'};

soap.createClient(url, function(err, client) {
    client.Hello(args, function(err,result,res){
        console.log(result);
        console.log(client.lastRequest);
    });
});
```

The Hello-function should return string "Hello test !". However, I get:

```
'Hello null !'
```

The request being sent is:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" ....><soap:Body>
<tns:Hello xmlns:tns="http://example/">
    <tns:name>test</tns:name>
</tns:Hello></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

where
    test
is the interesting part. The service is expecting

```
<name>test</name>
```

*without namespace* (i tested this with http://www.soapclient.com/)

So, the question is: how do I send the request argument without tns attached? (tns:name => name) Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The correct way to override namespace is to send the parameters like this:

```
var params = { ':name' : 'test' }
```

It's in documentation: [Overriding the namespace prefix](https://github.com/vpulim/node-soap#overriding-the-namespace-prefix)

Answer (score 0):

In your code instead of passing argument as

```
var args = {'name':'test'};
```

try

```
var args = {arg0: 'testName'};
```

I am not an expert but it worked for me to pass an argument from node.js while invoking SOAP client.